# What is the correct term for the plan stage of user interface design

Tags: user-interface

Is "Application Definition Statement" the correct term for the **plan/idea** stage that gets written down of user interface design? I mean before you even reach the stage of sketching > wireframing > prototyping.

And i also mean before any contact with the target market, i guess you could say the hypotheses stage.

And i mean with regards to myself doing this for a web application of my own and **not** when its for a client.

For a few days i have thought that it was called Requirements Definition but having looked at http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/plan/define-your-app.html i think that Application Definition Statement is what i should be calling it, im looking for confirmation/correction on this.

To clarify too, its for a web application not iphone or ipad its just that while im searching to find the right name i keep landing on apple.com at various pages, lol

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is called the "I've got an idea" stage.  Which is to say: you're so early that it doesn't have a name, and it doesn't really need a name yet.  It's not like someone's going to knock off points if you don't use the Correct Name for where you are as you're thinking through what might become an application.

Requirements definition is later in the process, after you've had some time to let your idea gel into something that could become an application.  Requirements definition is when you start to solidify your idea into something that will eventually get completed, and when you break down your idea into small manageable chunks (and eventually prioritize those chunks) that can be worked on.

Apple's term of "Application Definition Statement" is okay for stage, although I think that it's a rather grandiose term for something that you haven't started sketching out or researching or anything.  "I've got an idea" sounds like it's more descriptive of where you are.